# How to replace variables in build.xml of ant project in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have `java` project, based on `ant`. In my `build.xml` file i have `${build}` variable. So, if I am starting script manually, something like this:

```
BUILD_NUMBER="22"
sed -i "s/\${build}/$BUILD_NUMBER/g" /path/to/my/jenkinsworkspace/build.xml
```

it works.
But if i am using this
`sed -i "s/\${build}/$BUILD_NUMBER/g" ${WORKSPACE}/build.xml`
in my Jenkins-pipeline in the build-step, it does not work, i have error.

```
> Replace needed variables ...
[Pipeline] sh
+ sed -i s//6/g /path/to/my/jenkinsworkspace/build.xml
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
```

So, the question, how to change `${build}` in the `build.xml` with `${BUILD_NUMBER}` from my Jenkins-job ?

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i "s/\\\${build}/$BUILD_NUMBER/g" ${WORKSPACE}/build.xml`
Just add `\\`